# Transform and persist Spark DStream into several separate locations, in parallel?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have an use case of a DStream that contains data with several levels of nesting, and I have a requirement to persist different elements from that data into separate HDFS locations. I managed to work this out by using Spark SQL, as below:

```
  val context = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(duration))
  val stream = context.receiverStream(receiver)
  stream.foreachRDD {rdd =>
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate
    import spark.implicits._
    rdd.toDF.drop("childRecords").write.parquet("ParentTable")
  }
  stream.foreachRDD {rdd =>
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate
    import spark.implicits._
    rdd.toDF.select(explode(col("childRecords")).as("children"))
      .select("children.*").write.parquet("ChildTable")
  }
  // repeat as necessary if parent table has more different kinds of child records,
  // or if child table itself also has child records too
```

The code works, but the only issue I have with it, is that the persistence runs sequentially - the first stream.foreachRDD has to complete before the second one starts, etc. What I'd like to see ideally is for the persistence job for ChildTable to start without waiting for ParentTable to finish, as they're writing to different locations and would not conflict. In reality, I have about 10 different jobs all waiting to complete sequentially, and would probably see a big improvement in execution time if I'd be able to run them all in parallel.